# How to extract text between two words in second occurrence - unix shell scripting

Tags: bash, unix, awk, sed, grep

I am trying to extract a string that contains everything between two words of a string:

input:

```
Please find the text [ This is a sample text [ Hello World - Earth ] ]
```

output:

```
Hello World - Earth
```

Text that are present between the second occurence of "[" and "]"

Comment: This is one place where the greedy match of `grep`, `sed` etc, aren't really a problem, i.e. `echo  "Please find the text [ This is a sample text [ Hello World - Earth ] ]" | sed 's/^.*[[]//;s/[]].*$//'` : output ` Hello World - Earth` . Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

If your `grep` supports `-P` option (PCRE), would you please try:

```
grep -Po "\[.*?\[\K.+?(?=])" <<< "Please find the text [ This is a sample text [ Hello World - Earth ] ]"
```

- The `\K` sequence tells the engine to discard the preceding match out of
  the matched result which works as `lookbehind`.
- The pattern `(?=])` is the lookforward to match a right square bracket
  excluding the match from the result as well.

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk` you can do something like

```
$ awk -F'[][]' '{print $3}' <<< "Please find the text [ This is a sample text [ Hello World - Earth ] ]"
 Hello World - Earth
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E 's/^[^[]*\[(.*)\].*/\1/;s//\1/' file
```

Find everything between the first set of `[...`] and then repeat the process to find everything between the second set of `[...]`.

A programmable version:

```
 sed -E ':a;/^[^[]*\[(.*)\].*/!d;s//\1/;x;s/^/x/;/x{2}/{x;b};x;ta' file
```

Change the integer in `x{2}` for the depth required.

N.B. This works on a line by line basis and does not cater for quoted square brackets.